# Separation of very nonpolar mixtures using column chromatography

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, chromatography

I am conducting a synthesis using Buchwald-Hartwig coupling. Below is the TLC result after nearly all consumption of limiting starting material. Th is 2,3,5-tribromothiophene, which is the limiting starting material in my reaction and reac. is the reaction mixture. The left is 254 nm UV radiation, and the right is stain using sulfuric acid/formaldehyde. The eluent is hexane only.

[image: TLC image]

I don't have confidence about what materials does the spots correspond to and even whether the desired product is successfully synthesized or not. The chances are that some side reactions would occur. Therefore first I am considering separating two spots below the starting material and identify them with MS, IR or something. But Is this possible? Currently the eluent is only hexane but two spots are near the solvent front, and they are too close. Can I separate two spots in column chromatography? Even the third spot is also quite close to two spots that I want to separate.

Comment: In this situation, I would have attempted prep TLC to try to isolate some of the potential product...

Comment: I agree, prep TLC is the way to go

Comment: Given the separation, be careful not to overload the prep TLC, or you're going to need to do it again...

Comment: @Zhe I am a beginner in prep TLC, and some text says that use polar solvent. But in this case is it okay to use hexane?

Comment: Hexane would be my first try